# Group by on two tables and perform Left join on outcome VBA ADODB SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, database, vba, adodb

I want to perform `Group BY` on two csv files and then perform Left Join on the outcome of both tables through VBA ADO Query in Excel. My end motive is to print the recordset.

Here is what I have done so far.

```sql
     SELECT * FROM (
                   SELECT   f1.[c3],
                            f1.[c4],
                            f1.[c5],
                            f1.[c6],
                            Sum(f1.[c8]) AS SUMDATA
                   FROM     test1.csv F1 
                   GROUP BY f1.[c3],
                            f1.[c4],
                            f1.[c5],
                            f1.[c6]) AS f3
LEFT JOIN  SELECT * FROM   (
                SELECT   f2.[c3],
                         f2.[c4],
                         f2.[c5],
                         f2.[c6],
                         Sum(f2.[c8]) AS SUMDATA
                FROM     test2.csv f2
                GROUP BY f2.[c3],
                         f2.[c4],
                         f2.[c5],
                         f2.[c6]) AS f4
on  f3.[c3]+ f3.[c4]+ f3.[c5]+ f3.[c6] = f4.[c3]+ f4.[c4]+ f4.[c5]+ f4.[c6]
WHERE  f3.[SUMDATA] <> f4.[SUMDATA]
```

This shows a syntax error. How to implement this? Any help is much appreciated. TIA.

An update -

I manage to implement 1 `LEFT JOIN` and 2 `GROUP BYs` between 2 tables. As per the request, here are few details regarding my dataset.
It consists of fields - c1, c2 .... c8. 
c8 is my target field.

My expected output - I do not need c7, c1 and c2 in output sheet. The info of c7, c1 and c2 is irrelevant. I need to do 5 things with my data.

1. Group Sum the c8 field based on c3, c4, c5 and c6 fields in CSV file 1 and store target field as SUMDATA
2. Group Sum the c8 field based on c3, c4, c5 and c6 fields in CSV file 2 and store target field as SUMDATA
3. Find the mismatched SUMDATA field entries between CSV1 and CSV2 (I used `LEFT JOIN` for this on concatenated c3, c4, c5, c6 fields)
4. Find the entries which are present in CSV1 but not in CSV2
5. Find the entries which are present in CSV2 but not in CSV1

Currently, I manage to write the code that works till step 3. I need to store the grouped tables temporarily which I got from Step 1 and 2, to perform the steps 4 and 5 which can be done through 2 more `UNION`, `LEFT JOINs`, and `WHERE` combination. This is where I am stuck right now.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer but the formatting is important for readability.

It looks like there's a lot wrong with your SQL.

The syntax should look like this (assuming querying a csv works like you are thinking):

```
SELECT SUB1.Field1,
       SUB1.AggField AS Agg1,
       SUB2.AggField AS Agg2
  FROM (SELECT Field1,
               MAX(Field2) Agg_Field
          FROM Table1 T1
         GROUP
            BY Field1
       ) SUB1
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT Field1,
               MAX(Field2) Agg_Field
          FROM Table1 T2
         GROUP
            BY Field1
       ) SUB2
    ON SUB1.Field1 = SUB2.Field1
 WHERE SUB1.AggField <> SUB2.AggField;
```

Also, you are missing a comma here: F1.[c5] F1.[c6] in the first chunk.

Try fixing the SQL syntax like this and see where that gets you.

Comment: I have fixed the comma issues. I manage to execute the query for 1 condition now. Now I want to take the intermediate objects to perform the next condition. Facing issue in that part. Should I update the code?

Comment: Take a closer look at the syntax example I provided. Subqueries need to be wrapped in parenthesis and aliased separately. You are still trying to do SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN SELECT Field FROM Table2 ON Table1.Field = Table2.Field when it needs to be SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Field FROM Table2) T2 ON Table1.Field = T2.Field

Comment: Yep now I have T1 and T2. If I perform an UNION on using T1 and T2 I am getting  "..Could not find the object T1.txt" error. How do I perform the UNION accessing T1 AND  T2 without performing group by again?

Comment: It's really difficult to debug from that description without seeing the SQL. In general it's best to provide sample data and your expected result rather than SQL and an error message.

Comment: In comments I am unable to post the code. Should I update the code or should I open a new post? Can you guide me, please. TIA Data contains the fields c1, c2... c8. Both tables. I need to seggregate data present in one csv and not in other and vice versa. The code shown above does picks the mismatches. I need to pick the above condition as well along with the preliminary left join. Btw the data is huge. I can't open it.

Comment: Updating the code is preferable. This is a good guide - https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ The key takeaways are sample data in well formatted text, with the expected result of the transformation also in well formatted text. Then you can post your current attempt at the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179123/discussion-between-xkcvk2511-and-error-2646).

Comment: Add the link to the formatter to your answer. Most people don't know how easy this is.